# How can I make RUU 4.0 update on HTC Desire S?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, htc-desire-s

How can I make RUU 4.0 update on HTC Desire S?
After downloading the zip file, I don't know which are the next steps in to the update process.

Please give me detailed instructions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is an very easy process.

1. First make sure that you have the driver installed. If not install this simple driver http://downloads.unrevoked.com/HTCDriver3.0.0.007.exe by downloading and running the file.
2. After this unzip the RUU zip file you downloaded. You'll see one pdf file and one .exe file.
3. If you want you can read the instructions on pdf file.
4. Connect the phone and run the exe file and follow the step by step wizard.

Things to watch out for:

1. Make sure your phone has at least 60% charge.
2. This process will take around 10 minutes to complete, don't unplug the phone until the wizard says the process is complete.
3. Your phone will reboot during the process which is normal.